# How to set RBAC for a user to submit Argo workflow in a specific namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, argoproj, argo-workflows

I'm checking Argo and I would like to grant a specific namespace for a user (or multiple users) to use Argo workflow (and let the users access features such as artifacts, outputs, access to secrets). I have set up a user and created a namespace (testing in minikube). How should I bind roles for the user, namespace and Argo workflow?

Here is role and rolebinding yaml files I have now.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [“”] 
  resources: [“pods”]
  verbs: [“get”, “watch”, “list”]
```

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user1 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role 
  name: pod-reader 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great guide for you to have a step by step explanation how to create namespace, user and grant permissions to work with this user only in chosen namespace:

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-1-create-user-with-limited-namespace-access

[Step 1: Create the namespace](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#step-1-create-the-office-namespace)

[Step 2: Create the credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#step-2-create-the-user-credentials)

[Step 3: Create the role for managing deployments](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#step-3-create-the-role-for-managing-deployments)

[Step 4: Bind the role to the user](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#step-4-bind-the-role-to-the-employee-user)

[Step 5: Test the RBAC rule](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#step-5-test-the-rbac-rule)